# Finding acceleration of a curve in three dimensions

Tags: calculus

An aeroplane flying on a great circle, it was shown that its velocity in spherical coordinates is

$$ \mathbf{ v}(t) =  \frac{ \sin \gamma \sin t }{ \sqrt{1-\sin^2 \gamma \cos^2 t } } \mathbf{e_{\theta}} + \frac{ \cos \gamma}{\sqrt{1-\sin^2 \gamma \cos^2 t }} \mathbf{e_{\phi}}$$

where $γ$ is the angle of tilt from the equatorial plane. Also, we assumed $r$ to be $1$. Find $\mathbf{a}(t)$ and prove it is ${\bf proportional}$ to $\mathbf{e_r}$

### Try

Now, taking derivatives in spherical coordinates is difficult. I know that the position in rectangular coord is given by

$$ r = cos γ cos t  \mathbf{i} + sin t \mathbf{j} + sin γ cos t \mathbf{k} , $$

So, in rectangular coords,

$$ a(t) = - \cos \gamma \cos t \mathbf{i} - \sin t \mathbf{j} - sin \gamma \cos t \mathbf{k} = - r $$

Do I have to convert this back to spherical? is this a correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your ${\bf r}(t)$ as written is correct then your try is fine. It remains the question why you started to work with ${\bf e}_r$, ${\bf  e}_\phi$, and ${\bf e}_\theta$ to begin with. I have never seen your first formula before.

One easily computes $|{\bf v}(t)|^2\equiv1$, hence the plane is flying with constant speed $1$ on a circle of radius $1$. We therefore may as well look at the motion
$$t\mapsto {\bf z}(t)=\cos t\>{\bf e}_1+\sin t\>{\bf e}_2$$
in the plane of said great circle, whereby ${\bf e}_1$ and ${\bf e}_2$ are fixed orthonormal vectors in this plane. One computes ${\bf v}(t)=\dot{\bf z}(t)=-\sin t\>{\bf e}_1+\cos t\>{\bf e}_2$ and
$${\bf a}(t)=\ddot{\bf z}(t)=-\cos t\>{\bf e}_1-\sin t\>{\bf e}_2=-{\bf z}(t)\ .$$
This says that the acceleration ${\bf a}(t)$, considered as a vector in the tangent space  $T_{{\bf z}(t)}$, is at all times directed to the center of the circle. In your moving coordinate system this means that ${\bf a}(t)$ is $\>=-{\bf e}_r\in T_{\bf r}$ at all times.